# Textbox auto-adjusts width when keyboard is active (Mobile)

Tags: android, html, css

I have designed a form for both desktop and mobile browsers:

[image: When the keyboard is not active]

This somehow is the intended design of the page. However, when a user tries to input on the fields provided and the keyboard will be active, the page somewhat shrinks its size. Although the container just stays in place, the textboxes however shrinks:

[image]

The textboxes, images, and texts' size and width is based on the browser's viewport. `width: 12vh;`for example allows the page for it to perfectly fit on every browser. It was working all fine until I notice this issue lately. Is there a way to fix this? And is it okay to use `vh` or `vw` ?